# switching mobile menu from dropdown to collapse

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a wordpress site and the theme has for mobile a dropdown box that looks like a select box.
It's a bootstrap site. 
Is there an easy way to change it to the way the mobile looks like with that small box with 3 lines?

You can view the site here:
     http://regencysprayfoam.com/clickandbuilds/RegencyFoam/

Comment: Do you mean you want it to look sort of like this? https://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/ - If so, you're going to have to replace the existing navigation with a regular bootstrap nav

Comment: If I currently has superfish on it, do I need to take that off?